# Analytics Metdata API (Java)

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

I am trying to get the full list of allowed Dimensions and Metrics from the Metadata API and finding a problem accessing it as I am using the Reporting API v4 anyone has any idea how I can make something like this `Metadata.Columns.List("ga").execute()` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally what I did is I used the v3 client library for the Metadata API (separately from the v4 of the Reporting API from the corresponding client library) and been able to work with `analytics.metadata().columns().list("ga").execute();`